# Hover for a list item that has an id

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to add css for list items with different id's. I need to change up the css for the list item when it's hovered but they the :hover doest work when I attach it to the end of the id. Here's the way I have it.

```
.header-menu li#drop:hover{
background-image:url(images/menu-arrow.gif) 90% 50% no-repeat, -moz-linear-gradient(top, #E5E5E5, #EDEDED);
background-image:url(images/menu-arrow.gif) 90% 50% no-repeat, -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#E5E5E5), to(#EDEDED));
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient(startColorStr=#E5E5E5, endColorStr=#EDEDED) progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Glow(color=#888888, strength=1) progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(direction=180, strength=2, color=#888888);
}
```

Comment: You need to provide more information. Does the list item really have id=drop? Can you isolate the problem in a simple full document?

Comment: Some of the items in my list menu have a drop down and I added an arrow background to them. So I give those list items the id "drop" so I can give them that arrow. My problem comes when the li#drop is hovered and the hover background changes. So I need to add that arrow to that arrow background to the li#drop "hovered".

Comment: If you give several elements the same `id` value, as it sounds, then there’s the problem. The `id` values must be unique. Use a `class` attribute and class selector instead.

Comment: Still not working. Is this right? `.header-menu ul li.drop-work:hover{
background-image:url(images/menu-arrow.gif) 90% 50% no-repeat, -moz-linear-gradient(top, #E5E5E5, #EDEDED);
background-image:url(images/menu-arrow.gif) 90% 50% no-repeat, -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#E5E5E5), to(#EDEDED));
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient(startColorStr=#E5E5E5, endColorStr=#EDEDED) progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Glow(color=#888888, strength=1) progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(direction=180, strength=2, color=#888888);
}`

Comment: The markup, please. Or, preferably, a full document.

Comment: Sorry Im new at this. Heres a pastebin of the css and html. [link]http://pastebin.com/kkjvc5e2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code, as clarified in your pastebin data, appears to work, though the gradient effect is rather unnoticeable as the colors are so close to each other. If this answer is not satisfactory, please identify what you expected to happen and how it fails to happen on which browsers.